# Does anyone have any recommendations for learning about Scala 2.8 changes?

Tags: scala, scala-2.8

Up until now I've been using Scala 2.7.7 (with Programming in Scala as my main reference). But as I'm a relative n00b, and 2.8 seems as if it will be out soon, I thought it would be a good idea to start using 2.8 before I get into any bad/outdated habits.

I've seen http://www.scala-lang.org/node/1564 as a list of key new features, but does anyone have any recommendations on good articles which cover any/all of the new features in greater depth?

TIA,
Paul.

**UPDATE**: Have just found http://sites.google.com/site/scalatohoku/changes-and-improvements-on-scala-2-8 which seems as if it might have all the information there *somewhere* but was hoping for something a little easier to navigate (and preferably something I could download/print to read offline).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The true official source for current Scala improvements is:

**[SID: Scala Improvement Documents](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/233)**,
especially the [ones with a status "active"](http://www.scala-lang.org/sids?status=9#).

Those are PDF documents that you can easily download and read off-line.